# isEmpty() function not working properly in android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to android development and still learning the basics.

What I'm attempting to do is extract the user message from the Edit text, that is the user's name, and then begin another activity if the user clicks the button below the edit text.
But the condition is that the length of the name must not be 0 else, a toast message will be flashed saying to Enter The Name.
However, when I try to do so, the toast message appears even if the length of the name is greater than zero.

I'll be very thankful if someone helps me with this out.

MainActivity.kt

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)
    val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.name_txt)
    val name = editText.text.toString()
    button.setOnClickListener {

        if (name.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter Your Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sent to Next Activity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, name)
            }
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

activity_mai.xml

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name_txt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Your Name"
    android:maxLength="20"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.028"

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send Information"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name_txt"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.168" />
```

Comment: use breakpoints or log statements, what's the value of `name` by the time it gets to your if statement ?

Comment: `val name = editText.text.toString()` add this inside `setOnClickListener` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API is working correctly, you are using it wrong. When you execute this code

```
val name = editText.text.toString()
```

The name variable will be initialized with the value from the `EditText` at that point (in this case it will return an empty string). Any future modifications of the text inside the `EditText` will not be reflected in this variable (it's only one time query).

You would have to refactor the code to query the EditText each time you wand to perform the validation.

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    val name = editText.text.toString()
    if (name.isEmpty()) {
        ....
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val name = editText.text.trim().toString() //This will remove all white spaces
```

Try writing inside onClickListener

Comment: I tried as you suggested, but it is still not working

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `String.isNullOrEmpty` or `TextUtils.isEmpty` (they essentially do the same thing).

Also, as lulianPopescu pointed out, you need to get the text of the EditText inside the setOnClickListener(). As of now, you're getting the text even before you can enter any text.

Comment: I have tried every single thing, but it still isn't working

Comment: How is it "not working"? Explain further.

Comment: I changed the if statement to: if(name.isNullOrEmpty()) and tried running the app again, and if i tap the button it shows the toast message which is OK because the string is empty but as i enter some string in the edit text and then click the button, it still shows the same toast message and doesn't move forward to the next activity.

Comment: As lulianPopescu pointed out, you should get the text of the EditText inside the setOnClickListener().